# Starting forked-daapd service from GIT Install

Tags: git, mediaserver, itunes, daap

So I'm pretty new to Ubuntu/Linux so I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious. I installed/configured forked-dapd from the GIT Source https://github.com/ejurgensen/forked-daapd and followed the directions in the Install file. I didn't see any errors populate, but I notice that forked-daapd isn't running as a service. I tried starting the service like this:

```
service forked-daapd start
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/forked-daapd start
```

With no results.
The repository is cloned to /home/ericstout/forked-daapd/ so I also tried (this is probably very wrong):

```
sudo /home/ericstout/forked-daapd/fork-daapd start
```

I noticed that in /home/ericstout/forked-daapd/src/ there is an application forked-daapd, I tried double clicking it to start (nothing happens) and also tried:

```
sudo /home/ericstout/forked-daapd/src/fork-daapd start
```

With no avail. How do I get the service to actually run? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I had a version of forked-daapd running earlier, and it was working aside from not actually allowing me to play music from my remote machines in iTunes (12.1) and found a fix was pushed to the GIT Hub Repository, thus why I purged and started over.

Hope I gave you as much info as you need, let me know if you need more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a few things that needed to be done for this to work correctly.

First was running forked-daapd which was achieved by this:

```
sudo forked-daapd
```

This seemed to work, but when checking the running processes, forked dapped was not there, so I checked the log file and saw that there was an error initializing the database, and it was a permissions issue. For now, I set the access to root and the username in the forked-daapd config file to root as well and boom! We have a media server.

Since this is internal only we can get by with root for now, but its a good idea to create a new user to access it.

Hope this helps anyone that might have gotten stuck in the same spot as me.